# How can i insert/pass a value into a mail body from my Table View Cell in Xcode/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Well I have a problem with my app.
Just to say I m a beginner :)
I have TableViewControler and I am using func with dequeueReusableCell to return a cell I that is ok. But the problem is how to implement this cell(s) with their values into a body mail using MFMailComposeViewController.setMessageBody?
I m trying to pass an order which is in cells just like it is - in a table. That table a need to be visible in mail body. This parameter only takes String and cell is not visible (in scope here). Maybe should I transform cell into a html? And how should I do that?

//This values/cells I need to implement into a mail body//

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderProductsCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderViewCell

```
    let rowData = orderedProducts[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblNameOfOrderProduct.text = rowData.selectedProducts.name + " " +  rowData.selectedProducts.packaging + " " + rowData.selectedProducts.volume + " " + String(rowData.stepperNumber) + " x(kom)"
    cell.lblFromDistributor.text = "Od"
    cell.lblToStore.text = "Za"
    cell.tfOrderFromDistibutor.text = String(rowData.distibutor)
    cell.tfOrderToStore.text = String(rowData.store)
    cell.tfOrderFromDistibutor.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    cell.tfOrderToStore.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
   
  
    return cell
    
}
```

//This is MFMailComposeViewControlles - in the same Controller like Table View

```
func showMailComposer() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
       defAlert(name: "You Can't sent mail", message: "")
        return
    }
    
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["sample@.com"])
    composer.setSubject("Porudzbina")
    composer.setMessageBody ("Here i need to implement cell", isHTML: false) 
    present(composer,animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Do you just need the data that is in the tableView as text into the Mail view or you want the image of the TableView in your mail ?

Comment: Maybe you can add some code of tableview data methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt indexPath` which will be helpful to us to understand your issue.

Comment: @ShawnFrank I don't have images in cells only labels and text fields. So just data. I tried using that by index Path can't be found in scope inside MFMailComposeViewControler. I don't know is that enough you to understand, its a little confusing question...

Comment: I think you should paste the code of what you tried which is crashing and this will be useful for anyone seeing this question and myself to debug your issue.

Comment: @ShawnFrank I edited the question with code. Nothing is crashing because I don't know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your end goal completely, but let me share what I think you mean.

I believe you want all the texts from your table view to show inside the MailView as text.

And I understand all your products data is inside `orderedProducts` - correct me if I am wrong ?

So inside your `showMailComposer` function, you can maybe try this - I have added comments to new code I have added to your function:

```
func showMailComposer() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
       defAlert(name: "You Can't sent mail", message: "")
        return
    }
    
    // Start empty string
    var stringBuilder = ""
    
    // Loop through all your products
    for orderedProduct in orderedProducts
    {
        // Append string builder with products
        // Add all product properties you want
        stringBuilder += "\(orderedProduct.name), \(orderedProduct.packaging) \n"
    }
    
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["sample@.com"])
    composer.setSubject("Porudzbina")
    
    // Add string builder as text
    composer.setMessageBody (stringBuilder, isHTML: false)
    
    present(composer,animated: true)
}
```

Run this result and check if it is close to what you want, it will give an output like this:

[image: MFMailComposeViewController build text to send an email in iOS of all the data in a UITableView]

**Update**

If you want to format the text a bit better in the MFMailComposeViewController you can use HTML and you need to know some basics of HTML like table as you suggested or other techniques like div.

Here is example of your function using table to organize the output:

```
func showMailComposer() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
       defAlert(name: "You Can't sent mail", message: "")
        return
    }
    
    // Start htmlStringBuilder with opening table tag and 2 headers / columns
    // named Name and Packaging
    var htmlStringBuilder = "<table border = 1><tr><th style=\"padding:10px\">Name</th><th style=\"padding:10px\">Packaging</th></tr>"
    
    // Loop through all your products
    for orderedProduct in orderedProducts
    {
        // Start a new table row
        htmlStringBuilder += "<tr>"
        
        // Add name table data for this row in first column
        htmlStringBuilder += "<td>\(orderedProduct.name)</td>"
        
        // Add packaging table data for this row in second column
        htmlStringBuilder += "<td>\(orderedProduct.name)</td>"
        
        // End the current row
        htmlStringBuilder += "<tr>"
    }
    
    // End html tag
    htmlStringBuilder += "</table>"
    
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["sample@.com"])
    composer.setSubject("Porudzbina")
    
    // Add htmlStringBuilder builder as html
    composer.setMessageBody (htmlStringBuilder, isHTML: true)
    
    present(composer,animated: true)
}
```

The generated HTML from above code is actually like this

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding:10px">Name</th>
    <th style="padding:10px">Packaging</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Final result gives you data organized in a table.

[image: MFMailComposeViewController HTML email data from UITableView in swift for iOS]

This is just basic HTML and you can do more styling and change how the output looks as you wish.

Comment: unfortunately my ipad doesn't work so i can't test ... what a bad moment. But you understood what I want to do. Yes the data is in the orderedProducts  This really makes sense. As soon as I find a test device I report!

Comment: thanks so much. I overcomplicated so i didn't see the obvious solution. The next thing I'm trying to do is to put this data like in a table to just look nicer. I thought to put this in html to make a table?

Comment: @SuncicaMiladinovic - please see my update, it should help you start with HTML in mail body

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is the result that I wanted. I done little bit of html a few years ago so its familiar. You have been very helpful.

Comment: Glad to know it helped @SuncicaMiladinovic. If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer.